# JS Prototype methods act differently while accessing in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I am extending the array object with a new method called `custommethod` as follows and looping through the values inside an array. However, the looping through the indices also prints the name of the `property` which is extended via `Array.prototype.<method>`.

```
Array.prototype.custommethod = function() {
    console.log("Hello from Custom Method");
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "anothercustommethod", {
    value: function() {
        console.log("Hello from Another Custom Method");
    }
});
```

#### Loop through the array

```
> x = [1,2]
[ 1, 2 ]

> for (i in x) { console.log(i); }
0
1
custommethod
```

- Why doesn't the `anothercustommethod` get printed in this loop?
- Is using the `Object.defineProperty()` a safer way to create `Array.prototype`?

I am curious as to how the `for` loop in javascript actually works. Does it use `Object.keys()` internally? If so how does it print `custommethod` which is inside `__proto__` property but not `anothercustommethod` which is also inside `__proto__` property?

Comment: This is one reason why you should avoid using `for..in` on arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why doesn't the anothercustommethod get printed in this loop?**

`for in` iterates over those properties, which data descriptor `enumerable` is set to true.

In the [**Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

> **enumerable** 
>   true if and only if this property shows up during
>   enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object. Defaults to
>   false.

When using `defineProperty`, you can also pass an extra property - *enumerable*.
By default it is set to false.

```js
Array.prototype.custommethod = function() {
    console.log("Hello from Custom Method");
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "anothercustommethod", {
    value: function() {
        console.log("Hello from Another Custom Method");
    },
    enumerable: true
});

const x = [1,2]
for (i in x) { console.log(i); }
```

**Is using the Object.defineProperty() a safer way to create Array.prototype?**

There is nothing about safe. Try to change the build in prototypes rarely

Comment: Thanks Suren, Can something similar to `enumerable: true/false` also be done with `Array.prototype.method` without using `Object.defineProperty()`?

Comment: great ! i was about to write the same thing

Comment: You need to define via `defineProperty`

Comment: So for the 2nd part of the question I asked, It is safer to use `defineProperty()` while trying to create prototype methods? Also I am just curious, why is it by default `enumerable:true, writable: true, configurable: true` when doing `Array.prototype` and not the same in `Object.defineProperty()`?

Comment: Generally in most cases you don't need to have restrictions on the properties, so why by default it is set to `true`. Using `defineProperty` by default set the `writable` property to false and you can't change its value. Consider how difficult it will be if you will for each property set `writable` to true.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I use `Array.prototype.method = function(){}` and want to only read the values within an array `X = [1,2]` without using `hasOwnProperty()` check every time, the only other way to do this would be to take the length of the array and loop index by value of a counter?

Comment: You can also use `for of` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the property by this API:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array.prototype,'custommethod');//{value: ƒ, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array.prototype,'anothercustommethod');//{value: ƒ, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
```

see? the first one got:enumerable: true,the second one got:enumerable: false,

also other values is different too that is because the default settings is different when set by different API

acutally ,want to be more safe,you can use this API:

Object.getOwnPropertyNames

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype).filter(v=>v.endsWith('custommethod'));//["custommethod", "anothercustommethod"]
```

if there is symbol,you still need to

```
Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(Array.prototype);//[Symbol(Symbol.iterator), Symbol(Symbol.unscopables)]
```

Object.keys works like for in,they won't traverse property whose enumerable is false;

when you try to traverse property with other API,should think about these things